# Individual object map values in s:select in Struts2

Tags: list, select, dictionary, struts2, ognl

I am trying to put a `Map<String, Object>` into a dropdown and I'm having issues with it. What is happening is the list is being generated with my objects, and the drop down will just show me pointers to the objects, If the code is like this.

```
<s:select name="form.Clause" list="Clause" label="%{getText('Clause')}" requiredLabel="true" required="true" />
```

This will fill my select with object references. Although if I do this

```
<s:select name="form.Clause" list="Clause"  listValue="%{Clause.{clause}}" Value="%{Clause.{clause}}" label="%{getText('Clause')}" requiredLabel="true" required="true" />
```

This will fill the list with the proper values except it prints everything in the list in every selection.

```
<select name="form.Clause" id="frm_form_Clause" data-wet_aria_input="true" aria-describedby="frm_form_Clause_error" aria-required="true" Value="[(A), (B), (A), (B), (C), (A), (B), (A), (B), (A)]" required="true">
<option value="1">[(A), (B), (A), (B), (C), (A), (B), (A), (B), (A)]</option>
<option value="2">[(A), (B), (A), (B), (C), (A), (B), (A), (B), (A)]</option>
<option value="3">[(A), (B), (A), (B), (C), (A), (B), (A), (B), (A)]</option>
<option value="4">[(A), (B), (A), (B), (C), (A), (B), (A), (B), (A)]</option>
<option value="5">[(A), (B), (A), (B), (C), (A), (B), (A), (B), (A)]</option>
<option value="6">[(A), (B), (A), (B), (C), (A), (B), (A), (B), (A)]</option>
<option value="7">[(A), (B), (A), (B), (C), (A), (B), (A), (B), (A)]</option>
<option value="8">[(A), (B), (A), (B), (C), (A), (B), (A), (B), (A)]</option>
<option value="9">[(A), (B), (A), (B), (C), (A), (B), (A), (B), (A)]</option>
<option value="10">[(A), (B), (A), (B), (C), (A), (B), (A), (B), (A)]</option>
```

Which is closer but still incorrect, as I am looking for the options to look like this.

```
<option value="1">(A)</option>
<option value="2">(B)</option>
<option value="3">(A)</option>
<option value="4">(B)</option>
<option value="5">(C)</option>
<option value="6">(A)</option>
<option value="7">(B)</option>
<option value="8">(A)</option>
<option value="9">(B)</option>
<option value="10">(A)</option>
```

Is there some way to make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.{}` in `Clause.{clause}` is called a projection in OGNL and it creates a list of properties of that object. That is why you get all values in option tag.

Usually you should put just property name in `listValue` attribute but in your case you need to get value from map value then reference it like that `value.property_of_object`

```
<s:select list="Clause" listValue="value.clause" />
```

Comment: I've already tried that and it does not work. it gives a list with no values at all. Although I just tried something that will work in this situation. which is to make `listValue = "%{Value.{clause}}"` This works because I'm addressing clause property of the object stored in value, instead of the toString() on the list caused by `listValue="%{Clause.{clause}}" `

Comment: @IanGallant: This is again a projection. Show your object that is in `Clause` map.

Comment: Here is my code that creates the map I use `clauses.put(rs.getString("id"),new clause(rs.getInt("id"),utils.noNull(rs.getString("clause")),rs.getInt("paragraph_id")));` I was aiming to use a projection this entire time it looks like I just didn't know the correct one which I've found.

Comment: @IanGallant: I would still say that projection isn't needed see an update. You need to get value from the map and then get property of that object.

Comment: @IanGallant: You are probably seeing `[]` around values because you are using `Value.{clause}` projection which creates list.

Comment: You are correct about that, it is displaying as a list and I changed it from the projection to the Value.clause which works perfectly. Thank you for working with me as I slowly realized when not to use a projection.

Comment: @IanGallant: You are welcome. The projection is not needed in this case because `<s:select>` tag already iterates over collection and calls `listValue` for each element in it.

Comment: +1... first time I see  list projections happening randomly :)